# How to get a direct link from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, flysystem-google-drive

I know it is possible to get a link that will initiate a download of a file from Google Drive. But this is not exactly what I am looking for. I want to be able to have the link of a file with its extension.

For example, it is possible to do this with Dropbox. I am able to get a direct link if I change "www.dropbox.com" to "dl.dropboxusercontent.com". So if I have a video file, it will play on the browser's player instead of opening the page to download it.

With Google Drive I don't know how to do this. If I generate a direct link, it will then create a link that automatically starts a download. A direct link for a .txt file will not be rendered on the browser. It will be downloaded instead.

So, it is possible to have a direct link to a file in Google Drive that is not the direct link that starts downloading automatically, but instead with the directory/file.ext?

Comment: Currently There is no way for doing this .. Also it can not be posted on Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you need to understand about how the Google drive api works.

When you do a [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) with the Google Drive api it returns a [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource) this is the response for the file itself. The information about it that google is willing to share with us. There are two fields here you may find interesting

[image]

The first thing you should know is that a file has one or the other of these links not both.  If the file is a binary type for example an image you will be given a webContentLink which can be used to download the file,  If its say a google sheet then you will be given a webViewLink which can be used to view the file in Google Drive web application.

Which link you get depends entirely upon the type of file it is.  No matter which link you get you will still need to have permission to access this file.  So whoever clicks the link must have at the very least read permission to the file.

On the Google drive web application we can create links which can be shared with anyone and allow anyone to "access" there is no way to create these links VIA the api.

What you wish to do is out of scope for the Google drive api, probably due to security reasons. Also the simple fact that google drive api is not a file service api it a file storage system.  THere is a difference.